# Import text from a txt file as a list within a list, and manipulate that data with column / row coordinates

Tags: python, oop, text

I've googled around, and I can't seem to find a solution that matches what I'm trying to do.  I want to import text from a .txt file as a list within another list.  For example if I have a text file that looks like:

```
ggggg   
wwggg  
wggtg  
ggggg  
ggggg
```

'g' = grass, 'w' = water and 't' represents a town.

I imported the map file like this:

```
tilemap = []
with open('tilemap.txt') as input:
    for line in input:
        tilemap.append(line.strip().split(','))
```

But I don't think it returned what I wanted.  I want it to be formatted like:

```
tilemap = [
    ['g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g'],
    ['w', 'w', 'g', 'g', 'g'],
    ['w', 'g', 'g', 't', 'g'],
    ['g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g'],
    ['g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g']
]
```

So that I may manipulated it using a class object that tracks a user's position inside of the super list.:

```
class WorldSpace(object):
    def __init__(self, row, column):
        self.column = column
        self.row = row
        self.userpos = tilemap[row][column]

world = WorldSpace(0, 0)
```

If I were to declare the WorldSpace variable 'userpos' as tilemap[0][0], it should return the first string of 'g' in tilemap, correct?

If that is true, how can I go about importing the map as I have shown it above?  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are confused about what [`.split(",")`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) does, it will split by the character in the argument:

```
>>> "ggg".split(",") #no commas to split by.
['ggg']
>>> "g,g,g".split(",") #works when it is seperated by commas
['g', 'g', 'g']
```

In your case you simply want to cast the line to a `list` so you can simply change `line.strip().split(",")` to `list(line.strip())` although I'd recommend using list comprehension:

```
with open('tilemap.txt') as input:
    tilemap = [list(line.strip()) for line in input]
```

Answer (score 3):

You're splitting the string by commas, but in your example text file, there are no commas separating the characters.  Try:

```
tilemap = []
with open('tilemap.txt') as input:
    for line in input:
        tilemap.append(list(line.strip())
```